# Plotting a double barplot in Python with values coming from two different dictionaries

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two dictionaries of alphabets with values as the frequency of a character. When I try to plot them with my code below, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

---

```
import string
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

N = len(labels)

dict_1 = {'A': 0.08167, 'B': 0.01492, 'C': 0.02782, 'D': 0.04253, 'E': 0.12702, 'F': 0.02228, 'G': 0.02015, 'H': 0.06094, 'I': 0.06966, 'J': 0.00153, 'K': 0.00772, 'L': 0.04025, 'M': 0.02406, 'N': 0.06749, 'O': 0.07507, 'P': 0.01929, 'Q': 0.00095, 'R': 0.05987, 'S': 0.06327, 'T': 0.09056, 'U': 0.02758, 'V': 0.00978, 'W': 0.0236, 'X': 0.0015, 'Y': 0.01974, 'Z': 0.00074}
dict_2 = {'P': 0.05776173285198556, 'U': 0.05776173285198556, 'A': 0.09025270758122744, 'O': 0.05415162454873646, 'L': 0.1263537906137184, 'M': 0.02888086642599278, 'V': 0.06859205776173286, 'S': 0.061371841155234655, 'D': 0.02888086642599278, 'N': 0.032490974729241874, 'J': 0.04332129963898917, 'I': 0.021660649819494584, 'F': 0.036101083032490974, 'B': 0.032490974729241874, 'H': 0.08664259927797834, 'C': 0.007220216606498195, 'W': 0.032490974729241874, 'Y': 0.05415162454873646, 'X': 0.007220216606498195, 'Z': 0.05054151624548736, 'R': 0.007220216606498195, 'E': 0.0036101083032490976, 'K': 0.0036101083032490976, 'T': 0.007220216606498195}

X = np.arange(len(dict_1))
bar_width = 0.45

fig = plt.figure( figsize=(17,5) )

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(X, dict_1.values(), bar_width, color='blue', align='center', hatch='//')
ax.bar(X-bar_width, dict_2.values(), bar_width, color='green', align='center', hatch='//')
ax.legend(('Usual English','Your Text'), fontsize = 15)

plt.xticks(X-(bar_width/2), dict_1.keys())
plt.xlabel('Character', fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize = 15)
plt.title("Frequency Analysis", fontsize=17)
plt.show()
```

---

I built the code using the same dictionary as first and thought it would work had I a different dictionary of alphabets. When I use the same dictionary, I get the following plot:[image]

I want the plot to show two bars with different values (corresponding to the value from the dictionary it came from) for each character.

Comment: There are multiple questionable parts of your procedure, but the error probably comes from the fact that `X` and `dict_2.values()` have different length. You can't plot one as a function of the other. In other words, your two dicts likely have a different number of elements, making your plan fail.

Comment: The more fundamental problem seems to be that you assume the dictionaries to be sorted, which isn't the case, so even if they had the same number of elements the plot could easily get completely wrong.

Comment: I see, I guess I can make it so that the characters not in the dictionary to have value 0 and order the dictionary as well before plotting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow get values from each dict based on merged keys. Like this:

```
>>> d1 = {'A': 10, 'C': 20, 'B': 42}
>>> d2 = {'X': 13, 'B': 21}
>>>
>>> d1.keys()
dict_keys(['A', 'C', 'B'])
>>> d2.keys()
dict_keys(['X', 'B'])
>>> all_keys = sorted(d1.keys() | d2.keys())
>>> all_keys
['A', 'B', 'C', 'X']
>>>
>>> d1_values = [d1.get(k, 0) for k in all_keys]
>>> d1_values
[10, 42, 20, 0]
>>>
>>> d2_values = [d2.get(k, 0) for k in all_keys]
>>> d2_values
[0, 21, 0, 13]
```

Make the plot from `all_keys`, `d1_values` and `d2_values`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dict_1 = {'A': 0.08167, 'B': 0.01492, 'C': 0.02782, 'D': 0.04253, 'E': 0.12702, 'F': 0.02228, 'G': 0.02015, 'H': 0.06094, 'I': 0.06966, 'J': 0.00153, 'K': 0.00772, 'L': 0.04025, 'M': 0.02406, 'N': 0.06749, 'O': 0.07507, 'P': 0.01929, 'Q': 0.00095, 'R': 0.05987, 'S': 0.06327, 'T': 0.09056, 'U': 0.02758, 'V': 0.00978, 'W': 0.0236, 'X': 0.0015, 'Y': 0.01974, 'Z': 0.00074}
dict_2 = {'P': 0.05776173285198556, 'U': 0.05776173285198556, 'A': 0.09025270758122744, 'O': 0.05415162454873646, 'L': 0.1263537906137184, 'M': 0.02888086642599278, 'V': 0.06859205776173286, 'S': 0.061371841155234655, 'D': 0.02888086642599278, 'N': 0.032490974729241874, 'J': 0.04332129963898917, 'I': 0.021660649819494584, 'F': 0.036101083032490974, 'B': 0.032490974729241874, 'H': 0.08664259927797834, 'C': 0.007220216606498195, 'W': 0.032490974729241874, 'Y': 0.05415162454873646, 'X': 0.007220216606498195, 'Z': 0.05054151624548736, 'R': 0.007220216606498195, 'E': 0.0036101083032490976, 'K': 0.0036101083032490976, 'T': 0.007220216606498195}

all_keys = sorted(dict_1.keys() | dict_2.keys())
d1_values = [dict_1.get(k, 0) for k in all_keys]
d2_values = [dict_2.get(k, 0) for k in all_keys]

X = np.arange(len(all_keys))
bar_width = 0.45

fig = plt.figure( figsize=(17,5) )

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(X, d1_values, bar_width, color='blue', align='center', hatch='//')
ax.bar(X-bar_width, d2_values, bar_width, color='green', align='center', hatch='//')
ax.legend(('Usual English','Your Text'), fontsize = 15)

plt.xticks(X-(bar_width/2), all_keys)
plt.xlabel('Character', fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize = 15)
plt.title("Frequency Analysis", fontsize=17)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This solves half of the problem. What's missing is how to plot the data then.

Comment: I've updated the answer with untested complete solution :)